# On Cron run Open and save all Profile2 based user profiles

Tags: users

i have a RULES event on "Cron maintenance tasks are performed" and a action is attached to it "execute custom php code"

```
<?php
$old   = '1 day';
$old = strtotime("now - $old");
$query=db_select('profile','pf')
        ->condition('pf.created',$old, '<')
        ->fields('pf',array('uid','pid','created'));
$result=$query->execute();
foreach($result as $record){
$profile=profile2_load_by_user($record->uid);
profile2_save($profile);
}
?>
```

Error :

> Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to profile2_save() must be an instance of Profile, array given, called in /home/test/public_html/drupal_sedco_2/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/php.eval.inc(146) : eval()'d code on line 9 and defined in profile2_save() (line 292 of /home/test/public_html/drupal_sedco_2/sites/all/modules/profile2/profile2.module).

Any clues .
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`profile2_load_by_user` returns either a single profile **or an array of profiles** keyed by profile type. `profile2_save` expects a single profile.

It looks like in your particular case array is returned, so you need to:

1. Test what you got from `profile2_load_by_user`
2. If it's a single profile, use `profile2_save` directly.
3. If it's an array, either select the array element you need, or `foreach` over that array, calling `profile2_save` on each element.

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing , it was an array() ; Works now :)